# Subject of would

Tags: grammar

John 1:11,12 MSG - He came to his own people, but they didn’t want him. But whoever did want him, who believed he was who he claimed and would do what he said, He made to be their true selves, their child-of-God selves.

Is it:

- But whoever did want him, who believed [that] he was who he claimed
  and [that he] would do what he said, He made to be their true selves,
  their child-of-God selves.

  ```
           OR
  ```
- But whoever did want him, who believed [that] he was who he claimed
  and [who] would do what he said, He made to be their true selves,
  their child-of-God selves.

Comment: I think it can be read either way. I'm not sure. It's ambiguous

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR The English strongly supports the reading that the Word, not the believer, is the subject of "would do what he said". That's because we have parallelism between the verbs in the sentence.

---

There are two ways we could break down this parallelism: into two or into three parts.

As two parts:

> [**1** whoever did want] him, [**2** who believed] he was who he claimed and would do what he said

As three parts:

> [**1** whoever did want] him, [**2** who believed] he was who he claimed and [**3** would do what he said]

The three-part reading does not work. It is defective. This is because proper parallelism must have a consistent structure apart from the element that changes. Concretely, it's the repeated subject pronoun **whoever** and **who** that signal the beginning of an item in the list. If we had three items, we would be missing the repeated subject pronoun for the third item.

Since Eugene Peterson (or his editor) is a good stylist, he added the "who" of "who believed" — which could have been omitted — in order to force the two-item parallelism and prevent the three-item parallelism.

Compare this version without "who":

> whoever [**1** did want] him, [**2** believed] he was who he claimed and [**3** would do] what he said

If we don't repeat "who", then each parallel item is now only a verb and not subject + verb, which leads to ambiguity of the subject.

Note that a *poor* stylist, of whom there are many, could easily screw up the parallelism and write either version if they meant a three-item parallelism. Hence, if it were in your average blog post on the Internet or quickly written newspaper article proofread by a proofreading mill overnight, I would not bet on this interpretation. But a world-renowned Bible translation by a gifted writer and seen by many eyes before publication is likely to be more carefully edited and use parallelism intentionally to disambiguate.

---

By the way, the original Greek is not ambiguous. That's because it reads "as *many* as did accept him, *those* who believe," etc. with both the pronouns and the following verbs conjugated for plural, not singular. So Peterson's decision in English mirrors this.

Comment: If we had three items, we would be missing the repeated subject pronoun for the third item.???  You mean to say wouldn't? I think that was a typo. And yes I agree with your statement. If he meant who would do what he said then who wouldn't have been omitted.

Comment: @Koko No to the typo. I meant that, given the sentence that we *have*, if we tried to interpret it as three-item parallelism we would find the last "who" missing. On the other hand, if we wanted to create *proper* three-item parallelism, yes, we would need another "who".

Comment: Would love for the fly-by downvoter to explain what they believe could be deficient in this answer!

Comment: I haven't.  I swear. Dont even have enough points to do so

Answer (score -1):

It's the first choice:

> But whoever did want him, who believed [that] he was who he claimed and [that he] would do what he said, He made to be their true selves, their child-of-God selves.

If you have a sentence with ...and...and...and... then perhaps words will be omitted, but they are implied.

The nearby "subject" (or subject of a clause) is "he". That's the implied subject of "he would...".

The choice of "who" would be unclear for multiple reasons. "who" is already being used to refer to the "believers", and also to "who he claimed". So it shouldn't also be used with yet a third meaning to refer to "he".

Furthermore, if we are filling in the missing words, we should choose the most explanatory answers. "Jesus" is quite definite. "He" is somewhat clear. "Who" is the most questionable.

---

Let's consider the alternative.

"[who] would do what he said".  If "who" referred to the believers, that means:

"[who] would do what he commanded".

If "commanded" were the intended meaning the translator ought to write it that way, since "said" is ambiguous.